# I get this error when deploying reports. Why?

Tags: reporting, deployment

I get this error when deploying reports. Why?

> Action:  NO ACTION    
> Result:  FAILED    
> Problem: filterlanguage:
>   Invalid value specified: 1.

[image]

Comment: What are the filters for your report? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: added screenshot.

Comment: Are you deploying just that report? Or are there others?

Comment: There are a whole bunch of them.   I am getting this very same error on most of the reports.   Some are joined reports, some are simple tabular ones.

Comment: Amber, this is more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 9):

Filter Language isn't a normal filter but a special field in upper right corner in report editor.

[image: report wizard in org with Translation Workbench]

It's just a guess but please check whether you have Translation Workbench enabled (and same languages selected) in your source org but not in target org?

And if TW is enabled in both - is the language set on the report available in the target?

Comment: Thank you @eyescream.   Translation workbench is enabled in Source org and is not enabled in the destination org.  Also do you know if there would be issues if multicurrency status is different between the orgs?   Currently it is enabled in source and might be turned off later.  But can we deploy reports in the intermediate time when the status between the orgs is different.  I will check the language settings and share my results.

Comment: https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/admin_enable_multicurrency_implications.htm says you can't disable multicurrency mode once it's active (of course you could refresh & overwrite whole sandbox). I've never tried to do what you're doing... I think reports should be deployable as long as they don't have filter "amount > 100 EUR"

Answer (score 0):

This is for someone who is encountering this issue while creating 2 GP. Below are the 3 checks you need to check

1. project-scratch-def.json : "language": "en_US"
2. report folder: all the reports which use "language" attribute as "en_US" should be removed from the metadata
3. Translation workbench must be enabled